# how to have onclick function calling an external module file

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code

```
<div class="signup">
    <h2 class="form-title" id="signup"><span>or</span>Sign up</h2>
    <div class="form-holder">
        <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Name" />
        <input type="email" class="input" placeholder="Email" />
        <input type="password" class="input" placeholder="Password" />
    </div>
    <button onclick="signup(this)" class="submit-btn">Sign up</button>
</div>
<script type="module" src="/libs/ajax.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="/scripts/login.js"></script>
```

No from the onclick here, I would like to call a function signup that is inside my login.js file

```
    import { Ajax } from '../libs/ajax.js'
    let signup = (e) =>{
        console.log(e)
    }
```

The problem is, I am using type="module" because I would like to import script within that js file. But, by assigning a type module, the function is not found from the html file. If I remove import and remove type="module" it does work.

Is there a way to bind a function from the onclick without assign my function to window. scope ?

Comment: don't create `let signup`, use `function signup`, functions hoists in javascript, meaning they don't need order of declaration, they are always on top

Comment: I tried let, I tried function, I tried export function signup they all don't work

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there a way to bind a function from the onclick without assign my function to window. scope ?

No. Modules have their own scope. They don't create globals unless you do so explicitly.

Better to avoid using intrinsic event attributes in the first place. Bind your event handler from inside the module.

```
let signup = event => {
    console.log(event.currentTarget);
};
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener("click", signup)
```

Comment: why is it better to avoid using intrinsic event attributes? Also I was wondering if the module is big and still hasnt loaded and the button has already been painted how would you handle this?